# jQuery - Trouble With Index Numbering Tag Elements

Tags: jquery, indexing

I'm building a jQuery plugin that works with multiple unordered lists. I want to be able to give each li tag in each list an index-numbered class name, starting over with 1 in each list, like so:

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-panel">
    <li class="col-1">column 1</li>
    <li class="col-2">column 2</li>
    <li class="col-3">column 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ui-tabs-panel">
    <li class="col-1">column 1</li>
    <li class="col-2">column 2</li>
    <li class="col-3">column 3</li>
</ul>
```

This is the code I'm using to do it:

```
$('.ui-tabs-panel').find('li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('col-' + (i+1));
});
```

But instead, the output is this:

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-panel">
    <li class="col-1">column 1</li>
    <li class="col-2">column 2</li>
    <li class="col-3">column 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ui-tabs-panel">
    <li class="col-4">column 1</li>
    <li class="col-5">column 2</li>
    <li class="col-6">column 3</li>
</ul>
```

Instead of restarting from 1 for each ul, it continues as though it's not numbering a whole new set of li tags.

What do I need to do to make it start the count over with each new ul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going through all the `LI`s in one big batch. You have to go through the `LI`s of each `UL` separately:

To restart the counter for each `UL`, you must use nested `.each()`es.

```
$('ul.ui-tabs-panel').each(function() {         // Get al ULs with .ui-tabs-panel
    $(this).find("li").each(function(i) {        // Go through each LI of this UL

        $(this).addClass('col-' + (i+1));  // Add the right class

    });
});
```

### [Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpjd5/)

Note that instead of using classes, you might be able to use the **[nth child pseudo selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)** on the fly.

For example to select the 2nd `Li` in each `UL.ui-tabs-panel` you would do:

```
   // Select the second LI in each ul.ui-tabs-panel
$('ul.ui-tabs-panel li:nth-child(2)')
```

### [Try it out with the jsFiddle (hides the second LI in each UL)](http://jsfiddle.net/gDmEd/)

Comment: Thanks! I had tried using nested .each() functions since posting this question, but I guess I didn't have the syntax quite right.